# PHP regular expression, containg x in mid start with - and every char is 3

Tags: php, regex

Regular expression, containing `x` in mid, start with `-`.

I have more than 2000 URL that contain pattern look like `-120x150` in every URL I want replace than with space in PHP.

URLs:

```
http://domain.tld/2011/11/Moguru-e1321969743766-150x132.jpg
http://domain.tld/images/2012/12/am-e1355417696121-120x150.jpg
http://domain.tld/images/2010/12/zhai-e1292841067443-150x125.jpg

-150x112
-150x150
-106x150
-112x150
-107x150
-150x102
-150x127
-100x150
-95x150
-109x150
-150x150
-122x150
-150x100
-120x150
-150x125
-150x122
-150x80
-150x99
-150x141
-96x150
-99x150
-150x117
-150x90
-150x115
-150x105
-150x101
-150x140
-150x123
-150x146
-150x111
-129x150
-150x87
-140x150
-150x136
-145x150
-150x119
-143x150
-150x126
-150x78
-150x62
-150x75
-150x92
-150x94
-150x134
-150x120
-150x113
```

I used search, replace function:

```
$searchArray = array("-150x112","-150x150","-106x150","-112x150","-107x150","-150x102","-150x127","-100x150","-95x150","-109x150","-122x150","-150x100","-120x150","-150x125","-150x122","-150x80","-150x99","-150x141","-96x150","-99x150","-150x117","-150x90","-150x115","-150x105","-150x101","-150x140","-150x123","-150x146","-150x111","-129x150","-150x87","-140x150","-150x136","-145x150","-150x119","-143x150","-150x126","-150x78","-150x62","-150x75","-150x92","-150x94","-150x134","-150x120","-150x113","-142x150","-139x150","-150x139","-150x84");
$replaceArray = array("","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","");
$img=str_replace($searchArray, $replaceArray, $img);
```

It's not work well now I am trying to write regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is simple regex to match -###x###

```
-\d+x\d+
```

so as long as the pattern of the string remains as in question this will help you to match any resolution string eg `-120x150`

**[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/vL4rI2/1)**

php example

```
$string = 'http://domain.tld/2011/11/Moguru-e1321969743766-150x132.jpg
http://domain.tld/images/2012/12/am-e1355417696121-120x150.jpg
http://domain.tld/images/2010/12/zhai-e1292841067443-150x125.jpg';

$pattern = '/-\d+x\d+/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

**[php demo](http://ideone.com/18FLlM)**

Comment: May be worth while adding in the `preg_replace`, just to complete the answer.